# Close hover div in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11

when i hover one div this code is executed,and bizDetails is show,

now i want when mouse out in bizDetails div it's close

my code is

```
$("div.bizDetails").css("left", -$("div.images").width() / 2).fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $("body").mousemove(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).parent().hasClass("bizDetails") && !$(e.target).hasClass("bizDetails")) {
            $("div.bizDetails").fadeOut();
        }
    })
})
```

this code work fine in chrome and firefox

but in IE this work in the first use,and in the secound when i hover a div , bizDetails is show and Immediately close,

bizDetails HTML

```
<div class="bizDetails" style="left: -71.5px; display: block;">
    <img src="../static/css/images/img1.png">
    <h2>graphic</h2>
    <p>decription</p>
    <span>texttexttexttexttexttextex</span>
</div>
```

please help me

Comment: Have you tried to bind - Jquery.on() - mousemove event in your fadeIn callback, and then unbind - Jquery.off() -it in the fadeOut callback? http://api.jquery.com/on/   http://api.jquery.com/off/  (or if epascarello say - use normal event)

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Use mouseenter and mouseleave, not over and out.

Comment: @epascarello mouseenter and mouseleave not work fine

Comment: @keypaul thank's for your answer, is used on ,but not work,can you show me example from jquery off in my code?

Comment: The problem is the mousemove is a bad idea to hide it. You need to see if the element that you are over is inside of div.bizDetails.

Comment: @epascarello Do you have a great idea؟

Comment: `$(e.target).closest(".bizDetails").length` should be a check to see if you are in the element. But will that fix it? doubt it.

Comment: @epascarello ichanged code to this ,                           $("body").on("mousemove",function (e) {
                            if (!$(e.target).closest(".bizDetails").length && !$(e.target).hasClass("bizDetails")) {
                                    $("div.bizDetails").fadeOut();
                                }
                        })
but have same problem